# Sorting numbers for highscores in java

Tags: java, sorting, numbers

Ive got a highscore system for my game. and i want to be able to sort the numbers in acending order,ive got a way to sort the numbers

```
   public static int[] sort(int[] a){
    Arrays.sort(a);
    return a;
}
```

but how do i make it so the scores stay with the name of the player that set it?
for example 
 me:10
 you:50

You should be number 1 and me should be nubmer 2. how to i make it so that the string stays with the int when its sorted? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest is to create a class to hold the person's name and score. Make it implement the Comparable interface, in the `compareTo(...)` method compare the score of the current object, `this`, to the object being passed into the method, and then sort an array of objects of this class just as you're doing.

```
class MyFoo implements Comparable<MyFoo> {
  private String name;
  private int score;

  public MyFoo(String name, int score) {
     // ... etc...
  }

  // getter methods here

  public int compareTo(MyFoo other) {
    return score - other.getScore();
  }

  //.... etc...
}
```

Comment: ok,so a arraylist of a comparable object will sort into the right order with Arrays.sort? thanks for the help :D

Comment: Ok,will do also thanks for the quick way of doing the compare to return,i was doing it manually,with a if for each case :)

Comment: Ok,nearly got it,just cant work out how to add a new score to Score[],as i cant just to scores.add and I dont know how many scores are saved in the array

Comment: @JackPatrick: then use an `ArrayList<Score>` (if your class is called Score) as this collection is made for your exact situation -- you need an array like structure of flexible size.

Comment: Thats what i had,but Arrays.sort(score) doesnt work,as there is no sort(arraylist)

Comment: There's always `java.util.Collections.sort(score);`!

Comment: ok that works,but its the wrong way round, its lowest to highest(lowest at top) which isnt what i want

Comment: That is dictated by your `compareTo(...)` method. If you want to reverse the direction, then change this method. I think you can figure out how to do this. :)  Either that or use another Collections method to reverse the order of the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class `Player` that contains both the name of the player and its score, and the appropriate getters (`getName()` and `getScore()`), and you'll be able to sort an array of Players with

```
 Player[] players = ...
 Arrays.sort(players, new Comparator<Player> {
     public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
         return Integer.valueOf(p1.getScore()).compareTo(p2.getScore());
     }    
 }
```

Comment: Ah yes, your `compare(...)` method is better than my `compareTo(...)` as it handles the "edge" cases better. +1 vote